# Run automation script from a Action?

Tags: user-interface, configuration, customization, maximo, jython-2.7

I have Maximo 7.6.1.1.

I would like to run an automation script from a custom **Action** button (in WO List View).

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've created an automation script with an action as a launch point. And I think I need to somehow reference the action in Application Builder >> Select Action.

But I've been unsuccessful in doing this--I've just been making random guesses at which options to choose, and of course, it hasn't worked.

**How can I run automation script from a Action in WO List View?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first create a SIGOPTION for the application (in the Application Builder app), but with the description that you want to appear in the menu. Then, create an entry in the "select action" menu that references your sigoption (again, in the Application Builder app). You do not have to fill in any description or details in the menu entry, that will be inherited from the sigoption (which is why you created that first). Give yourself the permissions for this sigoption. This is the usual way to get a menu entry into the system to do something.

I skipped the key information to tie the sigoption/menu entry to a script for ease of explaining adding the menu entry, but there are two key things to do to make this entry run an automation script. The first is the sigoption must be named exactly the same as your action that you created for your automation script. The second is that you must select the radio button at the very bottom of the sigoption dialog, in the "Advanced Signature Options" section, labeled "This is an action that must be invoked by user in the UI".

With those things in place, your menu should now be configured to run your automation script when selected in the application.

Comment: Thanks! For my future reference, the *Advanced Signature Options* were collapsed by default. At first, I thought the content was missing, but then I realized I just needed to expand it.

Comment: Any idea where the **button label** for the custom action is stored?

Comment: Oops. I did incorrectly state that the label came from the sigoption itself. I'll edit the answer with the correct location of the label when I get logged back in to an environment later.

Comment: No, I was right. If you give the "Description" of the SIGOPTION a short enough value, that will be used as the label for the action. That can be overridden via the "Header" value in the "Add/Modify Select Action" dialog.